# one to one relation using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
    var Friend = sequelize.define('Friend', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId_1: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    userId_2: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
```

and

```
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
```

I have models named Friend, User like above that and...

I want to one-one association that Friend has names of each user_1, user_2 along [id] in User

```
"userId_1": "1",
"userId_2": "2",
"user_1": {
  "name": "User1 Name"
},
"user_2": {
  "name": "User2 Name"
}
```

like this,

How I solve this in Node-Express using Sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Define model like this :**

```
var Friend = sequelize.define('Friend', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId_1: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    userId_2: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
);

Friend.belongsTo(User, { as : 'user_1' , foreignKey : 'userId_1', constraints: false});
Friend.belongsTo(User, { as: 'user_2', foreignKey : 'userId_2' , constraints:false});
```

`constraints:false` depends upon `user_1` and `user_2` is madatory or not , if yes then you can remove it , if not then please keep it as it is.

**You can get data of both user like this**

```
Friend.findAll({
    ...
    include : [
        {
            model : User ,
            as : 'user_1' // <--------- Here is the magic
        },        {
            model : User ,
            as : 'user_2' // <--------- Here is the magic
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to query `Friend` and access the user's name, you need to create an association of the type `hasOne` between those two entities.

```
var Friend = sequelize.define('Friend', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    }
    Friend.hasOne(User, { as: 'user_1' }); // this will add the attribute user_1Id to Friend
    Friend.hasOne(User, { as: 'user_2' }); // this will add the attribute user_2Id to Friend
}
```

Then you can get the `User` object using `Friend.getUser_1()`

You can find more info about `hasOne` association [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#hasone).